# Data Flow Task - Using a parameter in a SQL Command in OLE DB Source

Tags: ssis

I have the following SQL Command in an OLE DB Source, in a data flow task:

```
Select Top 5000 * 
From ProcessHistory.ScribeDeadZone1
Where ScribeDeadZoneId > ?
```

At the moment this works fine. However, I'd like to replace the 5000 with a variable. I can't seem to get the syntax right because everything I try results in an error when I click the Parameters button to set the parameter. I've tried

Select Top ? * and Select Top (?) *. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Just an idea, could you not build a variable with the entire SQL statement and then use the `SQL Command from Variable` option?

Comment: @Gareth - Yes I could and I'm actually working in that direction until I get a firm answer to my post.

Comment: Gareth's comment IS the answer, and I was going to post it as such until I saw his comment.   His suggestion is the only way to do what you want.  Firm enough?  : )

Comment: @TabAlleman - Yes, and if someone wants to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If @Gareth doesn't get to it later today, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the SQL statement in a variable and then use the `SQL Command from Variable` option when defining the data source.

Comment: Can someone please give a bit more detail as to what is meant by building the SQL statement in a variable? When I choose SQL Command from Variable, the parameter button disappears and it says my query has a syntax error (I'm guessing from the question mark).